# how do you include a water level sensor device in rainmaker?

Tags: arduino, esp32

i mean, reading temperature and humidity values from a dht11 sensor is fairly easy since you can just declare:

```
TemperatureSensor temperature("Temperature");
TemperatureSensor humidity("Humidity");
```

but i also want to read values from my water level sensor and this is where i get stumped. i've checked the rainmaker documentation numerous times already but there is no specific type for adding this kind of device:

```
Standard Devices

Classes are defined for the standard devices.

Creating object of these class creates the standard device with default parameters to it.

Class for standard devices

- Switch

- LightBulb

- TemperatureSensor

- Fan
```

or yknow, maybe i'm just missing something? how can i include the water level sensor to my rainmaker app? any help is much appreciated

i tried searching for any resources concerning this but to no avail :(

Comment: You need to tell people what sort of thing you are talking about.  Nobody knows what sort of water level sensor you have or what sort of program you're trying to integrate it into.  If it is just a float device then it is probably just a contact closure and you can read it with a digitalRead.

Comment: there are tons of water level sensors out there. pick one that fits your needs, read the documentation and read the values with arduino